# Как добавить расширение в браузер с помощью arsenic?

Tags: python

Этот код работает отлично:

```
import asyncio

from arsenic import services, browsers, start_session, stop_session

service = services.Chromedriver(binary='./chromedriver')
browser = browsers.Chrome(**{"goog:chromeOptions": {
    'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
}})


async def start():

    session = await start_session(service, browser)
    await session.get('https://google.com')
    await stop_session(session)


asyncio.run(start())
```

Добавляю расширение:

```
browser = browsers.Chrome(**{"goog:chromeOptions": {
    'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
    "extensions": ["ifibfemgeogfhoebkmokieepdoobkbpo.crx"]
}})
```

Возникает ошибка:

[image: 1]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как правильно добавить расширение?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, надо брать файл с расширением, энкодить его в base64 и уже после этого передавать в опции.

Comment: @DiMithras, ты полностью прав! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Итак, ниже предствалена функция, которая кодирует расширение нужным образом.
При создании экземпляра браузера, ключу extensions нужно передать список из закодированных путей для всех расширений.

```
import base64
from typing import BinaryIO


def encode_extension_path(path:str) -> str:

    def _encode(file_data: BinaryIO) -> str:
        return base64.b64encode(file_data.read()).decode("utf-8")

    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return _encode(f)
```

Comment: Молодец что в ответ оформил 